# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have python 3.7 with 32bit and after I did `pip install pygame`, I'm still getting

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

when running my code. I'm using pycharm.

Comment: are you executing `pip install pygame`   from the command line?

Comment: yes, i already have it installed, but pycharm can't import the module or something

Comment: @altai click on the External Libraries link in the Project window in Pycharm. Can you see Pygame? It may be under site packages?

Comment: yes I can see it

Comment: How are you starting the project?

Comment: import pygame here is my entire code: https://imgur.com/a/9QNcJYp

Comment: It works in the python shell but not in pycharm, why?

Comment: What's the file called that you're running? Can you double check the project settings? Click on File > Settings > Project: (name of your project goes here) > Project Interpreter and see what it says for the interpreter there.

Comment: It should also show you the libraries that interpreter can see.

Comment: It's in users/name/pycharmprojects, the only ones i can see there is pip and setuptools

Comment: Does it have the path to the python interpreter you're using? At the top of the window?

Comment: It works now thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would just like to add to what the first answer is saying:
If you are using pycharm, it still won't work until you go to file >> settings >> >> [your project name] >> python interpreter. You will see a list of packages there. If pygame is on it, then good, else, you must double click on the field where the packages are. It leads you to a little pop up box where you can type in things. If you type in pygame, you should be able to install the package.

Answer (score 2):

To be sure that you installed the python3 proper module u need to use

```
pip3 install pygame
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error a few days ago! Thankfully, I found the answer.

You see, the problem is that pygame comes in a .whl (wheel) file/package. So, as a result, you have to pip install it.

Pip installing is a very tricky process, so please be careful. The steps are:-

Step1. Go to C:/Python (whatever version you are using)/Scripts. Scroll down. If you see a file named pip.exe, then that means that you are in the right folder. Copy the path.

Step2. In your computer, search for Environment Variables. You should see an option labeled 'Edit the System Environment Variables'. Click on it.

Step3. There, you should see a dialogue box appear. Click 'Environment Variables'. Click on 'Path'. Then, click 'New'. Paste the path that you copied earlier.

Step4. Click 'Ok'.

Step5. Shift + Right Click wherever your pygame is installed. Select 'Open Command Window Here' from the dropdown menu. Type in 'pip install py' then click tab and the full file name should fill in. Then, press Enter, and you're ready to go! Now you shouldn't get the error again!!!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have several instances of Pythion on your computer. You may install pygame in one instance, but IDE uses another.

Comment: While lacking in detail, this answer described the cause of the issue I was encountering.  I upgraded Python to 3.10 missing the fact that Python doesn't look to older version for installed modules.