# CLIPSpy: Getting "No module name 'clips._clips'" upon importing clips

Tags: python, linux, attributeerror, clips, clipspy

I have installed CLIPSpy from the git repository, and followed the instructions for installing with the source files. Yet after installing and running the python shell I get this error:

```
   `import clips
       .../clipspy/clips/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from clips.error import CLIPSError
       .../clipspy/clips/error.py", line 32, in <module>
    from clips.router import Router
       .../clipspy/clips/router.py", line 7, in <module>
    from clips._clips import lib, ffi
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clips._clips'`
```

Despite this error, if I run the same commands outside of my CLIPSpy directory, I can import clips but get a different error.

```
>>> import clips
>>> env = clips.Environment()
>>> env.assert_string("(test 12)")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Environment' object has no attribute 'assert_string'
```

My assumption is that **ModuleNotFoundError** may be responsible for the **AttributeError**.

**OS:** Arch Linux

**git-repo:** https://github.com/noxdafox/clipspy

I followed the advice of specifying the directory of clips, [using pyclips and import clips as a python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081317/using-pyclips-and-import-clips-as-a-python-module), to specify the location of clips but it still gives me the same error.

Installing CLIPSpy via *pip* gave 'satisfactory' results: [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786945/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pygame)

```
Requirement already satisfied: clipspy in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/clipspy-0.3.2_2_g7dd9ca2-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg (0.3.2-2-g7dd9ca2)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.0.0 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from clipspy) (1.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.0.0->clipspy) (2.19)
```

I tried re-installing clipspy via github many times, but the same issue persists. The interesting part is that I used pyclips as alternative for a while and it gave me the same error. It might be something to do with the directory or the installation, but I am not sure what it could be.

The installation process for CLIPSpy was as follows:

**make:**

```
python setup.py build_ext --include-dirs clips_source           \
        --library-dirs clips_source
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:484: UserWarning: The version specified ('0.3.2-2-g7dd9ca2') is an invalid version, this may not work as expected with newer versions of setuptools, pip, and PyPI. Please see PEP 440 for more details.
  "details." % self.metadata.version
running build_ext
generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/_clips.c'
already up-to-date
```

I tried re-installing setuptools to see if I could get a valid dist.py version, but alas nothing has changed.

**sudo make install:**

```
....
Installed /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/clipspy-0.3.2_2_g7dd9ca2-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for clipspy===0.3.2-2-g7dd9ca2
Searching for cffi==1.12.2
Best match: cffi 1.12.2
Adding cffi 1.12.2 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Searching for pycparser==2.19
Best match: pycparser 2.19
Adding pycparser 2.19 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Finished processing dependencies for clipspy===0.3.2-2-g7dd9ca2
```

The solution could be something simple, but I can't seem to know what it is.

Any help or advice on what to do or where I went wrong would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**
   After removing files related to clips, and having a fresh install, I no longer receive the **Atribute Error**. Rather I get an **ImportError**

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/clipspy-0.3.1-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/clips/__init.py", line 30, in <module> from clips.error import CLIPSError
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/clipspy-0.3.1-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/clips/error.py", line 32, in <module> from clips.router import Router
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/clipspy-0.3.1-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/clips/router.py", line 7, in <module> from clips._clips import lib ffi

Import Error: libclips.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've cloned the git repository that contains tag 3.2

**EDIT 2:**
   Managed to fix the error by renaming the *libclips.so.6* file located in the **/usr/lib/** folder to *libclips.so*
Now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the author of the `clipspy` module. I would rather suggest you to open a GitHub issue for these types of matters rather than a SO question.

As a general line, the issues you are suffering from indicate you are trying to install a Python module in a dirty environment. For example, installing via `pip` resolves in a noop because you ran `make install` beforehand and `pip` sees the package is already installed.

To install from git, you either git clone a [specific tag](https://github.com/noxdafox/clipspy/tree/0.3.2) or download the code from a [specific release](https://github.com/noxdafox/clipspy/releases/tag/0.3.2). `clipspy` uses tags to infer the version numbers hence you see the warning:

> UserWarning: The version specified ('0.3.2-2-g7dd9ca2') is an invalid version, this may not work as expected with newer versions of setuptools, pip, and PyPI. Please see PEP 440 for more details.

A common issue when installing `clipspy` is an old version of `setuptools`. Have you tried updating it to a more recent version?

```
# pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

One last note, do you happen to also have PyCLIPS installed within the system? The namespaces will conflict as the modules are both called `clips`. This would explain the error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Environment' object has no attribute 'assert_string'
```

Comment: You were right. I still had a version of clips installed which caused the AttributeError. I have done the pip command before but still the same issue. Thank you for helping me solve the issue.